# Phonegap error android sdk build.xml:950 : null returned: 1

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, cordova, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to launch phonegap android app in android sdk, but I am receiving an error:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/Users/me/Projects/one/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:950: null returned: 1
```

I followed this guide http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html but it is not working.

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 11):

You are most likely also getting the line

> invalid resource directory name:
>   /YOUR/PROJECT/ROOT/PATH/bin/res/crunch

right before the error codes, so open up terminal and enter the following:

```
cd YOUR/PROJECT/ROOT/PATH

rm -fR $(find . -type d -name crunch|xargs)
```

Comment: Line 950 is ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}" Did you make sure you have the assets configured correctly for Cordova? Check out https://github.com/dev-mobile/cordova-starter/blob/master/android_cordova_starter/build.xml

Comment: @confile I'm glad to hear it resolves the issue since the question appears abandoned by the original author.

Comment: This is really the only solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just had to cd into the platforms/android dir and run `ant clean` and it fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue. something that can help is to read `ant` `log` as recommend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878299/1211174)

to do so run `ant -logfile //antLogFile.txt release -f ./AppMain/build.xml`
or in the folder itself. i.e : `platforms\android` run `ant -logfile ./antLogFile.txt release`

My issue was a file with `Hebrew` characters on its name..

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sorry for the late answer

An alternative to other solutions possibly OS-X Specific but i was having the same issue and none of the solutions for me worked however the mention of assets made me go back and scour over my build logs and i noted this:

> [aapt] /Users/rowdoggnz/Development/cordova/surveyapp/platforms/android/assets/www/lib/fa/Icon
>   [aapt] : error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

This was the cause of my error which shared the same error code and line references as the original poster.

OS-X seems to generate ghost icon files for some reason which are not visible in finder due to being hidden, i used an app called "Invisiblix" to view my project folder and removed all of the 'Icon' files and my app would build fine.

I'm guessing the iOS build naturally ignores these Icon files however Ant doesn't.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I run `cd platforms/android` then `ant clean`. Then as you suggested I used InvisibiliX (that I was already using for various reasons) to find and delete all "Icon" files in the project. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one project and you are using the same assets eg: images, ant will fail to build. You can use ant clean to remove the cache from other projects and avoid this issue as suggested in this post [crunch/resource packaging with aapt in ant build uses cache from other projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970438/crunch-resource-packaging-with-aapt-in-ant-build-uses-cache-from-other-projects)

Nevertheless, In my case I just have one project with many images, some of them were called with the same name, but with different letter case. Ant's build process is case-insensitive, so those images were duplicated, being error cause.

My particular fix was to rename or eliminate one of the images to allow cordova build my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in OSX using Ionic framework. This was my fix:

I ran this on the command line in the project root folder:

```
find . -name Icon -exec rm {} \;
```

What the above does descend through the whole project to search for files name Icon. Upon finding them they are deleted.

After this I ran my build process and all was good again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the prerequisites correctly.